# Why if statement not working as expected?

Tags: java, android

I want to know why if statement not working as well and take first probably only?
here I want to go Mainactivity when webview is gone and when webview is visible go to pdfBooksActivity
this my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        WebView BookPdfWebView=findViewById(R.id.PdfBooksWebView);

        if (BookPdfWebView.getVisibility()== View.GONE){
            Intent x= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            x.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(x);
        }
        else{
            Intent x= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfBooksActivity.class);
            startActivity(x);
        }

}
```

Comment: (Take it as a dump answer from a non-android developer), could it be because when back is pressed the view is always GONE so it always satisfies your first part of if condition

Comment: yes sure, i did the same code in another project and work well but in this project i don't know why not work yet.

Comment: which part of condition is always executing? if or else ? I mean which activity it is taking you always despite of webview visibility ?

Comment: PdfBookActivity

Comment: Could you post your code that sets BokkPdfWebView’s visibility? Perhaps there’s a gotcha in there.

Comment: ok just minute i will post code

Comment: He says to me is too long and I could not add it, but my problem in back